# Adobe Animate ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property loopMode not found on _ and there is no default value

Tags: class, actionscript-3, actionscript, movieclip, adobe-animate

I faced below error when I add a .as class to a MovieClip in Adobe Animate 2019:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property loopMode not found on Symbol1 and there is no default value.
at privatePkg::___LayerProp___$/executeFrameHelper()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate CC 2019\Common\Configuration\Camera\Flash\privatePkg\___LayerProp___.as:87]
at privatePkg::___LayerProp___/executeFrame()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate CC 2019\Common\Configuration\Camera\Flash\privatePkg\___LayerProp___.as:68]
at Symbol1/applyLayerZdepthAndEffects()[Symbol1::frame1:17]
at Symbol1/frame1()[Symbol1::frame1:10]
at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
at runtime::AppRunner/run()
at ADLAppEntry/run()
at global/runtime::ADLEntry()


ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property loopMode not found on Symbol1 and there is no default value.
at privatePkg::___LayerProp___$/executeFrameHelper()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate CC 2019\Common\Configuration\Camera\Flash\privatePkg\___LayerProp___.as:87]
at privatePkg::___LayerProp___/executeFrame()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate CC 2019\Common\Configuration\Camera\Flash\privatePkg\___LayerProp___.as:68]
at privatePkg::___LayerProp___/enterFrame()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate CC 2019\Common\Configuration\Camera\Flash\privatePkg\___LayerProp___.as:63]
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property loopMode not found on Symbol1 and there is no default value.
at privatePkg::___LayerProp___$/executeFrameHelper()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate CC 2019\Common\Configuration\Camera\Flash\privatePkg\___LayerProp___.as:87]
at privatePkg::___LayerProp___/executeFrame()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate CC 2019\Common\Configuration\Camera\Flash\privatePkg\___LayerProp___.as:68]
at privatePkg::___LayerProp___/enterFrame()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate CC 2019\Common\Configuration\Camera\Flash\privatePkg\___LayerProp___.as:63]
```

The same project works on earlier version of Animate or flash without error.
The .as file has nothing special on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is happening when “Advanced Layers” is turned on .you have to turn off “Advanced layers” to be able to have some codes on your project.

1.Go to properties panel.

2.Click on “Advanced Settings”.

3.Uncheck mode “Use Advanced layers”.

4.Click ok .

Comment: Adobe said they are working on this problem with Advanced layers to solve the conflict.